# Como decodificar el password de un usuario en base de datos en Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony3

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Necesito saber si hay alguna funcion que me permita decodificar el password guardado en base de datos,pues el tema es que al sistema se accede desde una web externa que me envia por post un usuario y una contraseña y necesito compararlos con los que tengo en la base de datos.Tengo un archivo php donde tengo implementado el servicio web que me obtiene esos datos y luego se conecta al sistema para hacer esa verificacion.Debajo les pongo la linea del security.yml del encoder y las del controller cuando creo a un usuario desde el mismo sistema.

//Security.yml

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: bcrypt
    Assertsoft\MunicipalidadBundle\Entity\Usuario: bcrypt
```

//Controller

```
   $passwordCodificado =   $this->container->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($usuario,$usuario->getPassword());
   $usuario->setPassword($passwordCodificado);
```

Comment: No vas a poder hacer eso, ya que si fuera posible que sentido tendria usar encriptamiento de contraseña?  pero no entiendo bine tu problema dices que accedes de sde una web externa? es un servicio web?

Comment: Hay una web externa(un wordpress) que tiene un formulario de login,cuando el usuario se loguea en ese formulario debe poder acceder a mi sistema en symfony,el logueo solo puede ser desde ese wordpress.si funcionaria como un servicio web...en donde el deberia enviarme las credenciales y yo verificarlas con los datos que hay en base de datos,si coinciden pues deberia redirigirlo a la pagina de bienvenida de mi sistema

Answer (score 1):

Las comparaciones de contraseñas nunca decodifican la contraseña almacenada, sino lo contrario, codifican la contraseña recibida y la comparan de manera segura con la almacenada.

Para no complicarse con todos los detalles Symfony nos expone un servicio. Obtén una instancia de `"security.password_encoder"`. El método `isPasswordValid` recibe el password en texto plano y puede hacer lo que pides.